# spring aop logging advice is not getting called

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I am writing simple aspect with simple logging advice which will be called upon setter of class.

**Below is code Snippet**

**AopMain.java**

```
package com.example.test;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.example.test.model.Triangle;
import com.example.test.service.ShapeService;

public class AopMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        //ShapeService shapeService = context.getBean("shapeService", ShapeService.class);
        //shapeService.getTriangle().setName("triangle");
        Triangle triangle = new Triangle();
        triangle.setName("triangle class");
        System.out.println(triangle.getName());
    }
}
```

**Triangle.java**

```
package com.example.test.model;

public class Triangle {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println(name);
    }

}
```

**LoggingAspect.java**

```
package com.example.test.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.test.model.Triangle;

@Component
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Before("execution(public * *(..))")
    public void LoggingAdvice(JoinPoint jPoint) {
        System.out.println("Advice run. Get method is called " + jPoint.getTarget());
        Triangle triangle = (Triangle) jPoint.getTarget();
    }

    @Before("args(name)")
    public void test(String name) {
        System.out.println("logging advice args " + name);
    }

}
```

**Output**

**triangle class
triangle class**

**spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop   
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

    <!-- <bean id="triangle" class="com.example.test.model.Triangle">
        <property name="name" value="Triangle Name"></property>
    </bean> -->

    <bean id="circle" class="com.example.test.model.Circle">
        <property name="name" value="Circle Name"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="shapeService"
        class="com.example.test.service.ShapeService" autowire="byType" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.example.test" />
</beans>
```

spring is working properly.

I do not understand why aspect is not gettting called.
please help me to understand this issue.

Comment: I think just because i am initializing the triangle class with new keyword since it will not be a part of spring, that is the reason spring does not know about the aspect class. correct if i am wrong. this might be the reason.

Comment: you are correct. Spring AOP can only advice spring container managed beans . Also note that `"execution(public * *(..))` has a global scope , which means advice all method executions of all spring beans . This could have undesired results. A better scoping would be `"execution(public * com.example.test.model.Triangle.*(..))` for the example shared.

Comment: awesome, actually i thought of this only after posting the question. thanks buddy,

Comment: Well, you did't let Spring Container know that there is an aspect class.